# htaccess regular expression with a "/"

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm having a brain cramp. I'm using htaccess to rewrite a page and sometimes the variable that gets passed through will have a `/` (forward slash) in the variable. Sometimes there will be a slash and sometimes there won't but it is super important that all of this is treated as one variable. I'd really rather not reprogram all my pages with a `str_replace()` to switch a `-` for a `/` and then make a call to a database. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/accounting/finance.htm
```

`Accounting/Finance` is one variable that I need.....it is not in an accounting directory and then there's a page called finance.htm in accounting. So far I've got something like

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+.*[A-Za-z]*)\.htm$     mypage.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

But it doesn't like it.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

REPLY TO COMMENTS/ANSWERS

The specific rule that I'm looking for is something like this.....

[start of string]...1 or more letters...[possibility of a / followed by 1 or more letters].htm[end of string]

The two answers given below aren't working...I'm pretty sure it keeps treating it as a directory and not an actual "filename". As soon as I remove the forward slash the page works just fine...

Comment: Im rusty on regexps but can you do something like ([A-Za-z/])?

Comment: @DevinM I've tried [A-Za-z/]+ and it didn't seem to like that. I've also tried [A-Za-z\/]+, and [A-Za-z]+\/*[A-Za-z]+\.htm and it didn't like that either.

Comment: I think the reason your example there isn't working is that the ".*" is greedily eating everything to the end of the URL, so it has nothing left to match to the ".htm".

However, I'm not entirely clear what URLs you want to NOT match, so can't help beyond that. Do you want this rule to match anything ending ".htm"?

Comment: Investigate the `RewriteLog` configuration to find out why/when it fails.

Comment: I take it that `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ mypage.php?page=$1 [L]` won't cut it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i get you right, you just need this one:

```
([A-Za-z/]*)\.htm
```

it should work with every combination of / or not-/

e.g.

```
accounting/finance.htm
test.htm
```

Comment: I had some other custom characters I needed to throw in there. It was just the / for some reason that gave me the most grief...and who knows why. It works now, that's all I care about.

Answer (score 2):

A slash is just another character. Apart from that, your regexp looks unnecessarily complex. For instance, `.*[A-Za-z]*` is not different from `.*` and also `[A-Za-z]` can be shortened to `[a-z]` if you use the `[NC]` flag.

Your precise rules are not entirely clear, but you probably want something on this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z/]+)\.htm     mypage.php?page=$1
```